# How to slice off last two characters in a string then convert to a double?

Tags: python, arcgis, arcmap

I'm trying to do a field calculation in ArcMap from one field to another. I need to slice off the last two characters of one field, and convert to float (or double).

I'm trying to do this:

```
float(!StatedArea![-2])
```

My starting values (from the StatedArea field) are like this:
12.99 a
0.2377 a
0.0041 a

I just want to take off the space and the "a".

All I'm getting is ERROR 000539, with this message "ValueError: could not convert string to float"

Any ideas what the issue could be?

Comment: I don't know ArcMap, thus I will assume the notation `!StateArea!` is proper to ArcMap. To take off the 2 last element from a string, you have to use `:`. `str[:len(str)-2]`. The `[-2]` select the element before the last one, e.g. `"abcdef"[-2]` returns `"e"`

Comment: you would want to grab all values upto the last 2, this can be done with `[:-2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
float(!StatedArea![:-2])
```

should work.
You might want to revisit list indexing in python: 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm

Comment: This is it! I thought I had the colon in there but just didn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As already stated `[:-2]` will discard two last characters of `str`. I want to note that Python has no built-in `double` type. According to [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex) in most implementations, Python's `float` is equivalent to C `double`. Therefore if you will use `float`, you might expect precision equivalent to `double`.